# instant run requires that the platform corresponding to your target device is installed (error on emulator, not physical device)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

Before ill start, ill say that while this error does have a couple of threads dedicated to it, all are errors with physical devices and not emulators. My problem is with an emulator, which is a Pixel 2 API 26.

[image]

I have tried 2 things - I have clicked Install and Continue which produces the required result (there is an instant run) but next time I click instant run the message keeps coming.

Next thing i've done is I have manually downloaded the platform in question (oreo 8.0) from the SDK manager:

So I don't know why I am getting this error. And again mind you, it only happens with emulators and not physical devices. It also only happens with Oreo - I get no problems with emulators running API 28.
[image]